# Is the following the correct way to disable both E_WARNING and E_NOTICE in PHP

Tags: php

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php, I know the correct way to disable E_NOTICE in PHP is

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

I was wondering, is the following the correct way to disable both E_WARNING and E_NOTICE in PHP?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would do what you describe (turn off warnings and notices), yes. But if you actually want to turn off *everything*—which is highly recommended in production code—just use `error_reporting(0);`. There are [many types of errors, warnings, and notices defined in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)—and thus included in `E_ALL`<sup>*</sup>—that are not covered by `E_NOTICE` or `E_WARNING`.

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

> PHP 5.3 or later, the default value is **E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED**. This setting does not show **E_NOTICE**, **E_STRICT** and **E_DEPRECATED** level errors. You may want to show them during development. Prior to PHP 5.3.0, the default value is **E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT**. In PHP 4 the default value is **E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE**.

<sup>As of 5.4, all errors, notices, and warnings covered by any predefined `E_*` constant are included in `E_ALL`. See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can Use just simply that on your page.

```
error_reporting(0);
```